# 3-d array with different size of row and column

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, size

i am making a three-d array the problem i am facing is i want to create multiple 3-d array however with varying size of row and column so the first matrix size could be 0-2-2 while next matrix could be say 1-1-3 so on..

kindly do not suggest making a large matrix that could have value of all the row and columns.

i personally have tried using structure to create the code, i have defined 2-d array( for row and column) in the structure and then stored it in variable e[1].array(2-d), i have used for loop to continuously change value of row and column in array based on user input, the problem i am facing is every time the for loop changes value to next the code over writes itself hence previous values  of array can not be called so if for first matrix the size of row and column was 2-2 and next is 1-3 so e[1].x[2][2] have some value then for second loops e[1].x[1][3] the dimensions of x have been re-defined hence i could not call x[2][2].
kindly suggest ways i could store 3-d array with different size of row and column for each matrix.

```
 int main()
 {
 int matrix;
 printf("ENTER NUMBER OF MATRICES\n");
 scanf("%d`", &matrix);
 int row, column;


for (int m = 0; m < matrix; m++) {
    printf("ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS IN %d MATRICE\n", m + 1);
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("ENTER NUMBER OF column IN %d MATICE\n", m + 1);
    scanf("%d", &column);
     struct x {
  int f[row][column];
};
    struct x k[m];
    int g = 1;

    printf("ENTER ALL ELEMENT LEFT TO RIGHT\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        
        for (int u = 0; u < column; u++) {
            
            printf("%d)\n", g);
            scanf("%d", &k[m].f[j][u]);
            g = g + 1;
        }
    }
    for (int s = 0; s < row; s++) {
        printf("|");
        for (int l = 0; l < column; l++) {
             
            printf("%d", k[m].f[s][l]);
            if (l < column - 1) {
                printf("  ");
                
            }
        }
        printf("|\n");
        
    }
    printf("%d", k[0].f[0][0]); // error here calling over written 
 value
 }
  return 0;
```

expectation:

```
 ENTER NUMBER OF MATRICES
 2
 ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS IN 1 MATRICE
 2
 ENTER NUMBER OF column IN 1 MATICE
 2
 ENTER ALL ELEMENT LEFT TO RIGHT  
 1)
 1
 2)
 2
 3)
 3      4
 4)
 4
 |1  2|
 |3  4|
 ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS IN 2 MATRICE
 1
 ENTER NUMBER OF column IN 2 MATICE
 3
 ENTER ALL ELEMENT LEFT TO RIGHT
 1)
 5
 2)
 6
 3)
 7
 |5  6  7|
 1 // error here in output
```

Comment: Add some capitalization and formatting to the question and post some code. It is really hard to read

Comment: You say you want to create 3D arrays, but you describe examples in terms of just two dimensions.  I'm confused.

Comment: i have edited kindly have another look to understand in detail.

Comment: @john_bollinger i have defined just 2-d array but want multiple 2-d array say x[0][2][2] then x[1][1][3] so on...

Comment: Whast you're looking for is called a "jagged array", I think. The secret is that rather than an N-dimensional array of items, you want an (N-1)-dimensional array of pointers to items. Each pointer can  then point to a dynamically allocated 1-dimensional array of items

Comment: @vatsal did you have evaluate the possibility to use a 1d array and work only by index?

Comment: I guess `k[o]` is a typo and you meant `k[0]`. The lifetime of the array `k` is to the end of the current iteration of the enclosing `for` loop. The next iteration of the `for` loop creates a new array `k` that replaces the old one. The contents of `k[0]` in the next iteration are indeterminate because only the contents of `k[m]` are being filled in by that iteration. Also `k[m]` is out of bounds because the array was declared as `struct x k[m];` rather than `struct x k[matrix];`.

Comment: Wait, how did this compile?  VLAs can't be `struct` members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each matrix may be a different size, you should manage each matrix separately and record its dimensions separately. The code below shows how to use a structure type to do that.

Common C implementations support variable length arrays, so you use this to make addressing the matrix elements simpler. The program below shows how to use a pointer to a variable length array to point to the rows of a matrix. The memory address is recorded in the structure using `void *`, because we cannot have a variably modified type in the structure, but a separate variable is declared where it is needed, and it is set to the start of memory for the matrix.

In the absence of using variable length arrays, you would have to address the elements using manual arithmetic calculations into a linear array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    // Read the number of matrices.
    int NMatrices;
    printf("Enter the number of matrices:  ");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &NMatrices))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf for number of matrices failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (NMatrices < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, number of matrices is negative.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Define a type to manage a matrix.
    struct MatrixInformation
    {
        void *Memory;        // Memory for the matrix.
        int NRows, NColumns; // Number of rows and number of columns.
    };

    // Allocate memory to manage NMatrices matrices.
    struct MatrixInformation *Matrices = malloc(NMatrices * sizeof *Matrices);
    if (!Matrices)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Read each matrix.
    for (int m = 0; m < NMatrices; ++m)
    {
        // Read the number of rows and the number of columns of this matrix.
        int NRows, NColumns;
        printf("Enter the number of rows in matrix %d:  ", m+1);
        if (1 != scanf("%d", &NRows))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf for number of rows failed.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (NRows <= 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, number of rows is not positive.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Enter the number of columns in matrix %d:  ", m+1);
        if (1 != scanf("%d", &NColumns))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf for number of columns failed.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (NColumns <= 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, number of columns is not positive.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Create a temporary pointer for the matrix and allocate memory.
        int (*Matrix)[NColumns] = malloc(NRows * sizeof *Matrix);
        if (!Matrix)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Save the numbers of rows and columns and the memory address.
        Matrices[m].NRows = NRows;
        Matrices[m].NColumns = NColumns;
        Matrices[m].Memory = Matrix;

        // Get the values for the matrix elements.
        for (int r = 0; r < NRows; ++r)
            for (int c = 0; c < NColumns; ++c)
            {
                printf("Enter the element [%d, %d]:  ", r+1, c+1);
                if (1 != scanf("%d", &Matrix[r][c]))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf for element failed.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
    }

    // Print each matrix.
    for (int m = 0; m < NMatrices; ++m)
    {
        printf("Matrix %d:\n", m+1);

        // Get the numbers of rows and columns and the memory address.
        int NRows = Matrices[m].NRows;
        int NColumns = Matrices[m].NColumns;
        int (*Matrix)[NColumns] = Matrices[m].Memory;

        // Print each row.
        for (int r = 0; r < NRows; ++r)
        {
            // Start each row with a delimiter and no spaces.
            printf("|%d", Matrix[r][0]);

            // Print each element with two spaces for separation.
            for (int c = 1; c < NColumns; ++c)
                printf("  %d", Matrix[r][c]);

            // Finish each row with a delimiter and a new-line character.
            printf("|\n");
        }
    }

    // Free the memory of each matrix.
    for (int m = 0; m < NMatrices; ++m)
        free(Matrices[m].Memory);

    // Free the memory for the array of structures about the matrices.
    free(Matrices);
}
```

Comment: Moving `struct MatrixInformation` to file scope would allow a nice function to access a row, e.g. `int *MatrixRow(const struct MatrixInformation *mi, int row)` `{` `if (row < 0 || row >= mi->NRows)` `return NULL;` `else` `return (((int (*)[mi->NColumns])mi->Memory)[row];` `}`. Then row `r`, column `c` of `Matrices[m]` could be accessed as `MatrixRow(&Matrices[m], r)[c]` (assuming `m`, `r`, and `c` are valid).

Comment: Why do you a signed type for `NMatrices` when it isn't allowed to be negative? You could also remove a error check if you make it unsigned. Similar for `NRows` and `NColumns`, that don't need to be signed (as far as i see).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Because the original code is using `int`, and I do not want to change too many things at once and teach too many concepts unrelated to the question asked. Changing to use `size_t` (with `%zu` for `scanf`) would not actually eliminate an error check because, properly, you need to read the text and convert it with other routines and code to test the input format, since `scanf` does not have proper handling for out-of-bounds values. E.g., it will accept `-1` for `%zu`. And I do not want to get into all of that for this question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you for taking taking the effort and writing complete code however kindly inform is it possible for the program to print 1st matrix after taking input for rows and column of 1 and not wait for input of row and column of second matrix.  thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

first of all, in C you can not make dynamic array with syntax of static array. to understand what I say, just put a sizeof printf after defining array 'k'. something like this

```c
struct x k[m];
printf("size of k %li\n", sizeof k);
```

as you can see, the size of array return az 0. because at the compile time, the value of row and column are zero.

you should create your array dynamically inside heap. and link them using pointers. the best way is to use malloc.

---

first create an array of pointers based on value of the matrix variable.

```c
int* my_array;
...
my_array = (int*) malloc(matrix)
```

then in your loop take values of row and column and create new dynamic array for each of them

```c
int* inner_array;
for (int m = 0; m < matrix; m++) {
   ...
   inner_array = (int*) malloc(row * column);
   my_array[m] = inner_array;
```

and finally using inner_array to assign values of each array.

Comment: C supports variable length arrays.

Comment: The `malloc` calls are using the wrong size. `my_array` has the wrong type (it should be `int **`). But another problem is that each matrix can have different dimensions, but the information about the number of rows and columns for each matrix is not stored anywhere. Making `my_array` a pointer to a `struct` type that stores the dimensions solves that problem. Bonus points for including a flexible array member in the `struct` type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow please put the printf that I mentioned at first and you will understand what I said. what he want is kinda more complicated

Comment: @IanAbbott I didn't write the exact code. I give some hints to show the idea.

Comment: @BehnamGhiaseddin Your statement is entirely wrong. Your code has undefined behavior because the variable  m as I have understood is uninitialized or equal to 0. But you can assign it a value greater than 0 before the declaration of the array.

Comment: @BehnamGhiaseddin Let's assume the compiler supports zero-length arrays (e.g. the gcc compiler), then the size of `k` is only zero when `m` is zero.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow then why you don't write the answer without using malloc? This is about the different between heap and stack.

Comment: @IanAbbott then why you don't write the answer without using malloc? This is about the different between heap and stack.